I used annotations to Validate JSON but it doesn't work
I've got Controller
  @PostMapping(value = CREATE_TASK,
                 produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Schema(description = "Create task")
    public RestResponse createTask(@Valid @RequestBody TaskDto taskDto) {

            taskService.createTask(taskDto);
            return RestResponse.of(HttpStatus.OK,
                    "Task" + taskDto.getDescription() +" succesfully created",
                    null);
    }

Next I have DTO
public class TaskDto {
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean completed;
}

On some versions of dependencies Validation has been working, but for only description and it didn't work on completed
Here is my pom.xml
I tried to renew my depencies, used others but it didn't give me any effect
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>Kg.Rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>To-do-list</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>To-do-list</name>
    <description>To-do-list</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


So I have annotations to validate JSON, but the empty JSON still saving.

Remove the hibernate-validator dependency, that is already part of spring-boot-starter-validation and the version you decided to include is an incompatible version. Rendering your validation non working.

Tip: Instead of @NotNull private Boolean completed use private boolean completed (note the lower case b), then the value can't be set to null in the first place.
